# How do I resolve this error when installing a gem for sassy-buttons?

Tags: rubygems, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to use sassy-buttons for my Foundation 5 project. I used the following:

```
sudo gem install sassy-buttons
```

and get this error

```
ERROR:  Error installing sassy-buttons:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install <gemName>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong path, I discovered Bower.io for installing front-end dependencies. Here are the steps I went through.

- Install with Bower
- Add to foundation Config file
- Add_import_path "bower_components/sassy-buttons”
- Command line; compass install sassy-buttons
- Import partial to app.scss; @import "sassy-buttons/sassy-buttons”;
- Command line; compass compile
- Command line; compass watch
- Create a style and add mixin